# XlsxWriter: set display area when worksheet is opened

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter

When generated worksheet is opened by Excel, I always want to see the bottom rows rather than the topmost rows. Is there a method to do that?

For example, if there are 100 rows, I want to display rows 81 - 100, not 1 - 20, without hiding rows 1 - 80.

I can place the cursor by worksheet.set_selection() method, but that does not automatically make the selected cell visible.

Comment: That isn't supported in XlsxWriter (mainly because no-one ever asked for it). If you open a feature request I will look into adding it.

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that `freeze_panes()` has `top_row`. This is similar to what I wanted, but it only works when freezing panes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available in XlsxWriter >= 3.0.2 using the `set_top_left_cell()` worksheet method:

```py
    worksheet.set_top_left_cell(31, 26)

    # Same as:
    worksheet.set_top_left_cell('AA32')
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!